# TThread's Synchronize Behavior

Tags: delphi, synchronize

From what I understand, calling TThread's Synchronize will execute the synchronized code as if it was ran in the main thread. Let's say that in my main thread, I have one button:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 A, B, C : String;
begin
 A := 'test1';
 B := 'test2';
 C := 'test3';
 Button1.Enabled := false;
end;
```

In a secondary thread, I have the following code:

```
procedure TestThread.ChangeButton1;
begin
 Form3.Button1.Enabled := true;
end;
```

(Don't pay attention to the code itself -- it's just an example and it's *not* supposed to mean anything.)

Say I click on **Button1**, and right after, while **Button1Click** is being executed, TestThread calls **Synchronize(ChangeButton1);** Can we know when ChangeButton1 is going to be run by the main thread? If so, is it going to be after the whole of **Button1Click** has been executed; or can it be among any of the four operations inside the procedure?

Sorry if it's a silly question. I have been unable to find the answer to that question. It would allow me to understand better how the Synchronize procedure works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a silly question.

Synchronize actually switches to the main thread temporarily, so it is not 'as if' - the code is literally run on the main thread. If the main thread is doing something when Synchronize is called, the Synchronize call must wait for the main thread to go idle. Similarly, if a synchronized call is executing, anything else that needs to take place on the main thread must wait for the synchronized call to complete.

So for this scenario there is no interrupting one operation mid-stream to switch to something else.

Answer (score 7):

A `Synchronize()` request is put into a queue and then a message is posted to the main message queue to signal that the Synchronize queue is pending.  When the main message loop processes that message, the `Synchronize()` code is then executed.  `Button1Click()` is also triggered by a window message, so the main message loop is blocked while `Button1Click()` is running. If `Synchronize()` is called during that time, the synched code will not execute until control is returned to the main message loop.  So, to answer your question, `ChangeButton1()` will execute after `Button1Click()` has finished and exited.